# RPC from both client and server in Go

Tags: go, rpc

Is it actually possible to do RPC calls from a server to a client with the `net/rpc` package in Go? If no, is there a better solution out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently using thrift ([thrift4go](https://github.com/pomack/thrift4go)) for server->client and client->server RPC functionality. By default, thrift does only client->server calls just like net/rpc. As I also required server->client communication, I did some research and found [bidi-thrift](http://joelpm.com/2009/04/03/thrift-bidirectional-async-rpc.html). Bidi-thrift explains how to connect a java server + java client to have bidirectional thrift communication.

## What bidi-thrift does, and it's limitations.

A TCP connection has an incomming and outgoing communication line (RC and TX). The idea of bidi-thrift is to split RS and TX and provide these to a server(processor) and client(remote) on both client-application and server-application. I found this to be hard to do in Go. Also, this way there is no "response" possible (the response line is in use). Therefore, all methods in the service's must be "oneway void". (fire and forget, call gives no result).

## The solution

I changed the idea of bidi-thrift and made the client open two connections to the server, A and B. The first connection(A) is used to perform client -> server communication (where client makes the calls, as usual). The second connection(B) is 'hijacked', and connected to a server(processor) on the client, while it is connected to a client(remote) on the server. I've got this working with a Go server and a Java client. It works very well. It's fast and reliable (just like normal thrift is).

Some sources.. The B connection (server->client) is set up like this:

### Go server

```
// factories
framedTransportFactory := thrift.NewTFramedTransportFactory(thrift.NewTTransportFactory())
protocolFactory := thrift.NewTBinaryProtocolFactoryDefault()

// create socket listener
addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9091")
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Error resolving address: ", err.Error(), "\n")
    return
}
serverTransport, err := thrift.NewTServerSocketAddr(addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Error creating server socket: ", err.Error(), "\n")
    return
}

// Start the server to listen for connections
log.Print("Starting the server for B communication (server->client) on ", addr, "\n")
err = serverTransport.Listen()
if err != nil {
    log.Print("Error during B server: ", err.Error(), "\n")
    return //err
}

// Accept new connections and handle those
for {
    transport, err := serverTransport.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        return //err
    }
    if transport != nil {
        // Each transport is handled in a goroutine so the server is availiable again.
        go func() {
            useTransport := framedTransportFactory.GetTransport(transport)
            client := worldclient.NewWorldClientClientFactory(useTransport, protocolFactory)

            // Thats it!
            // Lets do something with the connction
            result, err := client.Hello()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Errror when calling Hello on client: %s\n", err)
            }

            // client.CallSomething()
        }()
    }
}
```

### Java client

```
// preparations for B connection
TTransportFactory transportFactory = new TTransportFactory();
TProtocolFactory protocolFactory = new TBinaryProtocol.Factory();
YourServiceProcessor processor = new YourService.Processor<YourServiceProcessor>(new YourServiceProcessor(this));


/* Create thrift connection for B calls (server -> client) */
try {
    // create the transport
    final TTransport transport = new TSocket("127.0.0.1", 9091);

    // open the transport
    transport.open();

    // add framing to the transport layer
    final TTransport framedTransport = new TFramedTransport(transportFactory.getTransport(transport));

    // connect framed transports to protocols
    final TProtocol protocol = protocolFactory.getProtocol(framedTransport);

    // let the processor handle the requests in new Thread
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (processor.process(protocol, protocol)) {}
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across [rpc2](https://github.com/cenkalti/rpc2) which implements it. An example:

Server.go

```
// server.go
package main

import (
 "net"
 "github.com/cenkalti/rpc2"
 "fmt"
)

type Args struct{ A, B int }
type Reply int


func main(){
     srv := rpc2.NewServer()
     srv.Handle("add", func(client *rpc2.Client, args *Args, reply *Reply) error{
    // Reversed call (server to client)
    var rep Reply
    client.Call("mult", Args{2, 3}, &rep)
    fmt.Println("mult result:", rep)

    *reply = Reply(args.A + args.B)
    return nil
 })

 lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:5000")
 srv.Accept(lis)
}
```

Client.go

```
// client.go
package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "github.com/cenkalti/rpc2"
 "net"
)

type Args struct{ A, B int }
type Reply int

func main(){
     conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:5000")

     clt := rpc2.NewClient(conn)
     clt.Handle("mult", func(client *rpc2.Client, args *Args, reply *Reply) error {
    *reply = Reply(args.A * args.B)
    return nil
   })
   go clt.Run()

    var rep Reply
    clt.Call("add", Args{5, 2}, &rep)
    fmt.Println("add result:", rep)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

RPC is a (remote) service. Whenever some computer requests a remote service then it is acting as a client asking the server to provide the service. Within this "definition" the concept of a server calling client RPC has no well defined meaning.

Comment: What I wanted to know was, when a client connects to a server, can the server send a request to the client using the stream that was used from the client to connect to the server?

Comment: "Remote procedure call" does not mean a client issues a request, it only means that a host intend to call a procedure on a remote host. Not sure what client/server has to do with it.

Comment: @Pierre-LucBertrand: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call): "An RPC is initiated by the _client_, which sends a request message to a known remote _server_ to execute a specified procedure with supplied parameters."_ It's about the semantics. A computer serving a request is always the _server_.