# Thrift RPC in two directions

Tags: c++, thrift

I am searching for a way to create rpc call from server to client.
Is this possible using thrift? In other words i would like to call RPC in two directions without creating another TSocketServer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional communication in thrift is not very well documented. It's not "normal" thrift usage.

I recently answered a question like this but for the language Go. I hope you can use my answer there as inspiration for a C++ solution. [RPC from both client and server in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166004/rpc-from-both-client-and-server-in-go/13184355)

Answer (score 0):

I am personally not a thrift expert but I did take a look at it when it was still in incubator phase.
And with a lot of other RPC mechanisms I did not find a way to handle async callbacks with thrift.
So whenever I have the need for this I am still stuck with corba. [TAO](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/TAO.html) is one of my favorite.
But I would really appreciate it if some could prove me wrong.

Answer (score -1):

TCP connection is full-duplex -> you have descriptors either on client side and server side. Just write to them e.g. using system calls

I'm sure after you serialize thrift message you can send it like regular unsigned char*.

Comment: You are right, but this is a little low level operation. What if I use  different transport method instead of TCP? There must be better way to do this in thrift's way.

Comment: I think this is an example you could check out, looks like there are few ways to do what you want. Based on this thrift file http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/contrib/transport-sample/Sample.thrift it provides this functionality. Example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/contrib/transport-sample/